# MYSQL error with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a simple table using jdbc, but it gives me an error. This is my code :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook","scott","tiger");
        System.out.println("part 1:DONE !");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String query = "create table Enrollment (ssn char(9), courseId char(5), dateRegistered date, grade char(2)"+
                    "primary key (ssn, courseId), foreign key (ssn) references Student (ssn), foreign key (courseId) references Course(courseId)";

        statement.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("part 2:DONE !");
    }
}
```

I am getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `grade char(2)`.

Comment: Yes... you are right. But now it gives me an other error :(

Comment: I found the mistake. I havent close the main paranthese at the end. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You have missed closing parenthesis ')' in your code. Use below statement in code.

String query = "create table Enrollment (ssn char(9), courseId char(5), dateRegistered date, grade char(2)"+
                    "primary key (ssn, courseId), foreign key (ssn) references Student (ssn), foreign key (courseId) references Course(courseId))";

Please make sure closing parenthesis.